# Non-zero exit status while regenerating during component build in chromium

Tags: chromium

I have tried configuring Component Build in Chromium but while regenerating the chromium.gyp_env by running    [link](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/component-build)

```
gclient runhooks
```

i get following error

```
C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src>gclient runhooks

________ running 'C:\chromium\depot_tools\python_bin\python.exe src/build/downlo
ad_nacl_toolchains.py --no-arm-trusted --keep' in 'C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tar
ball\tarball\chromium'
C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\native_client\toolchain\.
tars\toolchain_win_x86.tar.bz2 is already up to date.
win_x86: already up to date.
C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\native_client\toolchain\.
tars\naclsdk_win_x86.tgz is already up to date.
win_x86_newlib: already up to date.
C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\native_client\toolchain\.
tars\naclsdk_pnacl_win_x86.tgz is already up to date.
pnacl_win_x86: already up to date.
C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\native_client\toolchain\.
tars\naclsdk_pnacl_translator.tgz is already up to date.
pnacl_translator: already up to date.

________ running 'C:\chromium\depot_tools\python_bin\python.exe src/build/linux/
install-arm-sysroot.py --linux-only' in 'C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarba
ll\chromium'

________ running 'C:\chromium\depot_tools\python_bin\python.exe src/chrome/insta
ller/linux/sysroot_scripts/install-debian.wheezy.sysroot.py --linux-only --arch=
amd64' in 'C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium'

________ running 'C:\chromium\depot_tools\python_bin\python.exe src/chrome/insta
ller/linux/sysroot_scripts/install-debian.wheezy.sysroot.py --linux-only --arch=
i386' in 'C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium'

________ running 'C:\chromium\depot_tools\python_bin\python.exe src/tools/clang/
scripts/update.py --mac-only' in 'C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chro
mium'

________ running 'C:\chromium\depot_tools\python_bin\python.exe src/build/win/se
tup_cygwin_mount.py --win-only' in 'C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\ch
romium'

________ running 'C:\chromium\depot_tools\python_bin\python.exe src/build/util/l
astchange.py -o src/build/util/LASTCHANGE' in 'C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball
\tarball\chromium'

________ running 'C:\chromium\depot_tools\python_bin\python.exe src/build/util/l
astchange.py -s src/third_party/WebKit -o src/build/util/LASTCHANGE.blink' in 'C
:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium'

________ running 'C:\chromium\depot_tools\python_bin\python.exe src/build/gyp_ch
romium' in 'C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium'
Enabled Psyco JIT.
Updating projects from gyp files...
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Redist\D3D\x86\d3dcompiler_46.dll
Hook ''C:\chromium\depot_tools\python_bin\python.exe' src/build/gyp_chromium' to
ok 637.08 secs

________ running 'C:\chromium\depot_tools\python_bin\python.exe src/build/landmi
nes.py' in 'C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\build\get_landmin
es.py", line 63, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\build\get_landmin
es.py", line 58, in main
    print_landmines(options.target)
  File "C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\build\get_landmin
es.py", line 29, in print_landmines
    if (distributor() == 'goma' and platform() == 'win32' and
  File "C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\build\landmine_ut
ils.py", line 20, in inner
    ret = func()
  File "C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\build\landmine_ut
ils.py", line 60, in distributor
    if 'goma' in gyp_defines():
  File "C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\build\landmine_ut
ils.py", line 20, in inner
    ret = func()
  File "C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\build\landmine_ut
ils.py", line 48, in gyp_defines
    for arg in shlex.split(os.environ.get('GYP_DEFINES', '')))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/build/landmines.py", line 133, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "src/build/landmines.py", line 127, in main
    set_up_landmines(target, landmines)
  File "src/build/landmines.py", line 59, in set_up_landmines
    out_dir = get_target_build_dir(landmine_utils.builder(), target,
  File "C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\build\landmine_ut
ils.py", line 20, in inner
    ret = func()
  File "C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\build\landmine_ut
ils.py", line 102, in builder
    if platform() == 'android':
  File "C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\build\landmine_ut
ils.py", line 20, in inner
    ret = func()
  File "C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\build\landmine_ut
ils.py", line 73, in platform
    if 'OS' in gyp_defines():
  File "C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\build\landmine_ut
ils.py", line 20, in inner
    ret = func()



  File "C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball\chromium\src\build\landmine_ut
ils.py", line 48, in gyp_defines
    for arg in shlex.split(os.environ.get('GYP_DEFINES', '')))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
Error: Command C:\chromium\depot_tools\python_bin\python.exe src/build/landmines
.py returned non-zero exit status 1 in C:\chromiumtrunk\home\src_tarball\tarball
\chromium
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error it looks like there is something wrong with your GYP_DEFINES environment variable. what does `echo $GYP_DEFINES` output? It should be a set of space separated key=value pairs.